# Multiple foreign keys on sequelize (one-to-many or many-to-many)?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have two tables: users and alerts. Users should be able to upvote and downvote on alerts.

My models are defined like that:

Alert

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Alert = sequelize.define("alert", {
        ID: { type: DataTypes.BIGINT(11).UNSIGNED, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
        title: DataTypes.STRING,
        alert_type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function(models) {
                Alert.belongsTo(models.user, {
                    onDelete: "CASCADE",
                    foreignKey: {
                        allowNull: false
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    return Alert;
};
```

User

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var User = sequelize.define("user", {
        ID: { type: DataTypes.BIGINT(11).UNSIGNED, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
        user_login: DataTypes.STRING(50),
        user_pass: DataTypes.STRING(50),
        user_email: DataTypes.STRING(50),
    },
    {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function(models) {
                User.hasMany(models.alert);
            }
        }
     });
     return User;
};
```

What's the way of doing it using sequelize.js and MySQL(InnoDB)?

Should I use belongToMany() ?
Something like :

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var AlertVote = sequelize.define("user_alert_vote", {
        ID: { type: DataTypes.BIGINT(11).UNSIGNED, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
        vote_up: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        vote_down: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    {
        classMethods: {
        //    belongToMany(models.alert, ...);
        //    belongToMany(models.user, ...);
        }
     });
     return AlertVote ;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have here a 'many-to-many' relationship between a `User` and an `Alert`:

- A `User` can vote zero or many `Alert`s
- An `Alert` can be voted by zero or many `User`s

In addition, the relationship has properties that are `upVote` and `downVote` (I will not discussion your design to have these two properties as I'm not aware about the details of the use case).

As such, you need to use `.belongToMany()` on `User` and `Alert`.

A abbreviated code would be as follows:

```
var User = sequelize.define('User', {})
var Alert = sequelize.define('Alert', {})
var AlertVote = sequelize.define('AlertVote', {
    upVote: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    downVote: DataTypes.INTEGER,
})
Alert.belongsToMany(User, {through: 'AlertVote'});
User.belongsToMany(Alert, {through: 'AlertVote'});
```

For more details, please refer to [Belongs-To-Many associations](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/associations/#belongs-to-many-associations) from the official documentation.